# Подсчет совпадений в массиве

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как можно подсчитать количество совпадений в массиве? Допустим у меня есть массив `0,2,2,4,2,4`. Мне надо вывести, что `2 - 3 раза, 4 - 2 раза`. Вопрос тормозится тем, что я никак не могу найти, можно ли в *Delphi* в массиве давать свои названия элементов вместо порядковых номеров. Это бы облегчило задачу, а в данном контексте я могу подсчитать количество совпадений, но когда я второй раз попаду на `2` она второй раз просчитает количество совпадений, что мне не нужно.

```delphi
program 444;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses Windows;
const N=5;
type NArray = array[1..N] of integer;
var A: Narray; i,j,temp,min: integer;
  LCnt: Integer;
  LPrevVal: Integer;
begin
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

  for i:=1 to N do
    begin
      A[i]:= random(3);
      write(A[i], ' ');
    end;
  writeln;
  for i:=1 to N-1 do
   begin
    min:=i;
    for j:=i+1 to N do if A[j] < A[min] then min:=j;
    temp:=A[i];
    A[i]:=A[min];
    A[min]:= temp;
   end;
  j:=1;
  LPrevVal := A[j];
  LCnt := 1;
  for i := 1 to N do begin
    if A[i] <> LPrevVal then begin
      Writeln(LPrevVal, ' - ', LCnt, ' раз');
      LPrevVal := A[i];
      LCnt := 1;
    end else
      Inc(LCnt)
  end;
  Writeln(LPrevVal, ' - ', LCnt, ' раз');

  for i:=1 to N do write(A[i], ' ');
  Writeln;
  Writeln('Press Enter to exit...');
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная задача решается в два этапа

1. Сортировка исходного массива
2. Подсчет рядом стоящих значений

```delphi
var
  Data: array of Integer;
  Li: Integer;
  LCnt: Integer;
  LPrevVal: Integer;
begin
  if Length(Data) = 0 then
    Exit;
  Sort(Data);  // Такой процедуры нет. Нужно написать самому

  LPrevVal := Data[Low(Data)];
  LCnt := 1;
  for Li := Low(Data) + 1 to High(Data) do begin
    if Data[Li] <> LPrevVal then begin
      Writeln(LPrevVal, ' - ', LCnt, ' раз');
      LPrevVal := Data[Li];
      LCnt := 1;
    end else
      Inc(LCnt)
  end;
  Writeln(LPrevVal, ' - ', LCnt, ' раз');
end;
```

Comment: не проще словарь, и проход по массиву?

Comment: @teran учитывая Delphi7 нужно еще оценить, что проще и эффективнее - своя реализация словаря, или сортировка.

Comment: а, да, проглядел этот момент. Но мне кажется вопрос то не в том, чтобы вывести, а в том, чтобы использовать эти значения далее. Как вариант решения можно и StringList использовать для хранения, не по назначению, конечно, но как костыль.

Comment: Я вроде как провожу сортировку по этому алгоритму, но значение раз получаю на один больше

Comment: @teran Для хранения уже может использоваться произвольная структура. Заменить `Writeln` на `Add` труда не составит. Но автор просил именно вывести

Comment: @Erm Если у Вас есть код и Вы хотите, чтобы в нем нашли ошибку, то логично было бы предоставить этот код

Comment: но он спрашивал, как задать свои ключи (_то есть сделать словарь_), поэтому я и решил. что он хотел таки хранить

Comment: @teran _Мне надо вывести_

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, добавил код

Comment: @Erm Я изменил свой код, с учетом произвольной индексации массива

Answer (score 0):

Использовать структуру данных "словарь", как советует **teran**, было бы лучше всего, но коль скоро идёт речь о delphi 7, то могу предложить пару других способов.

**Способ 1 - максимальная близость к условиям задачи**

Вы пишете: "можно ли в Delphi в массиве давать свои названия элементов вместо порядковых номеров?"
И таки это есть, правда только в строковом виде. Я имею в виду класс `TStringList`. Индексированные свойства `Names`, `Values` и `ValueFromIndex` - к вашим услугам. Пример кода будет чуть ниже.

**Способ 2 - максимальное быстродействие + простота**

Это [сортировка подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC). Эффективна тогда, когда имеется малое количество **различных** элементов массива. Суть алгоритма проста - выполняется подсчёт встречаемости каждого из возможных значений массива.

**Пример кода**

```
program Example;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses Windows, SysUtils, Classes;
const N = 5;
type NArray = array of Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
  A: NArray;

// переформатированная версия авторского кода
procedure Authors_Proc(A: NArray);
var
  i, j, temp, min: Integer;
  LCnt, LPrevVal: Integer;
  data: NArray;
begin
  data := Copy(A);

  for i := Low(data) to High(data) - 1 do
  begin
    min := i;
    for j := i + 1 to High(data) do
      if ( data[j] < data[min] ) then
        min := j;

    temp := data[i];
    data[i] := data[min];
    data[min] := temp;
  end;

  j := 0;
  LPrevVal := data[j];
  LCnt := 1;

  for i := Low(data) + 1 to High(data) do
  begin
    if ( data[i] <> LPrevVal ) then
    begin
      WriteLn(LPrevVal, ' - ', LCnt, ' раз');
      LPrevVal := data[i];
      LCnt := 1;
    end
    else
      Inc(LCnt);
  end;
  WriteLn(LPrevVal, ' - ', LCnt, ' раз');
end;

// метод с использованием класса TStringList
procedure Strings_Proc(data: NArray);
var
  i: Integer;
  sName: string;
  strings: TStringList;
begin
  strings := TStringList.Create();
  try
    for i := Low(data) to High(data) do
    begin
      sName := IntToStr(data[i]);
      strings.Values[sName] := IntToStr(StrToIntDef(strings.Values[sName], 0) + 1);
    end;

    for i := 0 to strings.Count - 1 do
      WriteLn(strings.Names[i], ' - ', strings.ValueFromIndex[i], ' раз');
  finally
    strings.Free();
  end;
end;

// метод сортировки подсчётом
procedure CountingSort_Proc(data: NArray);
var
  i, max: Integer;
  tmp: array of Integer;
begin
  max := data[0];
  for i := Low(data) + 1 to High(data) do
    if ( data[i] > max ) then
      max := data[i];

  SetLength(tmp, max + 1);

  for i := Low(tmp) to High(tmp) do
    tmp[i] := 0;

  for i := Low(data) to High(data) do
    Inc(tmp[data[i]]);

  for i := Low(tmp) to High(tmp) do
    if ( tmp[i] > 0 ) then
      WriteLn(IntToStr(i), ' - ', tmp[i], ' раз');
end;

begin
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

  SetLength(A, N);
  for i := Low(A) to High(A) do
  begin
    A[i] := random(3);
    Write(A[i], ' ');
  end;
  WriteLn;
  WriteLn;

  Authors_Proc(A);
  WriteLn;

  Strings_Proc(A);
  WriteLn;

  CountingSort_Proc(A);
  WriteLn;

  WriteLn('Press Enter to exit...');
  ReadLn;
end.
```